# How to extract full paths from grep output using regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, expression

I need to automatically detect any USB drives plugged in, mounted or not, mount the ones not mounted already in folders that have the name of the given name of the device (like it happens in a Windows machine by default) and get the routes of the mount points of all the devices. The devices should be mounted in folders in /media/pi (using a Raspberry Pi, so pi is my username). This is what I'm doing:

To get the path of all mounter devices:

1) Run `lsblk`, outputs:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 14.4G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1 14.4G  0 part /media/pi/D0B46928B4691270
sdb           8:16   1 14.3G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   1 14.3G  0 part /media/pi/MI PENDRIVE
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14.9G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 41.8M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 14.8G  0 part /
```

2) With a particularly crafted line, I can filter out some unnecessary info:

I run `lsblk | grep 'sd' | grep 'media'` which outputs:

```
└─sda1        8:1    1 14.4G  0 part /media/pi/D0B46928B4691270
└─sdb1        8:17   1 14.3G  0 part /media/pi/MI PENDRIVE
```

I need to get `/media/pi/D0B46928B4691270` and `/media/pi/MI PENDRIVE`, preferably in an array. Currently I'm doing this:

```
lsblk | grep 'sd' | grep 'media' | cut -d '/' -f 4
```

But it only works with paths that have no spaces and the output of grep is not an array of course. What would be a clean way of doing this with regular expressions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ echo "$f"
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 14.4G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1 14.4G  0 part /media/pi/D0B46928B4691270
sdb           8:16   1 14.3G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   1 14.3G  0 part /media/pi/MI PENDRIVE
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14.9G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 41.8M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 14.8G  0 part /

$ grep -o '/media/.*$' <<<"$f"
/media/pi/D0B46928B4691270
/media/pi/MI PENDRIVE

$ IFS=$'\n' drives=( $(grep -o '/media/.*$' <<<"$f") )

$ printf '%s\n' "${drives[@]}"
/media/pi/D0B46928B4691270
/media/pi/MI PENDRIVE
```

Comment: First of all, what does echo "$f" do? I see that in your terminal it is doing the same as lsblk but I don't know why or how it happened.

Secondly, I ran lsblk | grep -o '/media/.*$' <<<"$f" and got no output whatsoever. But I see you get the result I need, each of the paths in a different line and isolated from everything else. How would you put that in a script?

Thanks!

Comment: he put your text in a variable and used it in the grep command.  but I don't know why using `<<<` and why just `<` isn't working

Comment: @user3290570 In my system `lsblk` produces a completelly different output, thus i assigned your lsblk output in a variable `f` to be able to make a test with results similar to your system. In your case you just need to run `lsblk | grep -o '/media/.*$'` or to put the results in an array just run `IFS=$'\n' drives=( $(lsblk |grep -o '/media/.*$' ) )`

Comment: @Mohamed With grep, sed, awk and other various commands you can use `<file` to feed grep from a file. In most cases you can just append the file after your command, i.e  `grep 'pattern' file`.  When you need to feed grep, sed, etc by text stored in a variable you need to use the `<<<"$variable"` format. Is equivalent like using `echo "$variable" |grep 'pattern'`

Answer (score 3):

`lsblk` supports json output with the `-J` flag. I would recommend that if you want to parse the output:

```
lsblk -J | jq '..|.?|select(.name|startswith("sd")).mountpoint // empty'
```

Comment: Interesting. Just checked a SuSE Leap 42.2 box, no `-J` option, but on Arch, it's there. Good to know.

Comment: Running that line in a terminal in my RPi outputs "jq: command not found"

Comment: @user3290570 just install it. `apt-get install jq`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, I was also surprised that they support `-J`

Comment: OK now it works for me like a charm as well. How would you do that with the regex (\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\n) ? (example to show that it works: https://regex101.com/r/1my59P/2)

Comment: I don't get the question. Why should I use that regex?

Comment: Just because it's short and it's the one I came up with that works.

Comment: Well, what if the drive is mounted somewhere else?

Comment: PS: If you want to use a regular expression, I would have probably used `lsblk -r | grep -oP '^sd[^/]*\K.*'`